# python start subprocess with no wait

Tags: python

I know there are tons of this questions, and trust me i think i have read them all.....

I have this script i need to start and just continue the "parent" script, and maybe there start another. I don't want to wait to check result, because i do logging in the child scripts.

```
    command = 'D:/scripts/py/tview/venv/Scripts/python.exe D:/scripts/py/tview/build/activities/subSystemScan_upload_scanner.py'
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
    try:
        p.wait(timeout=5)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        print("\n*TimeoutExpired*\n")
        pass
```

If i just run the p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True) alone, then it just "blink" with messages: *<Popen: returncode: None args: 'D:/scripts/py/tview/venv/Scripts/python.exe ...>* and it is not runned at all

If i add any type of check of the process like this p.wait it is working, and it terminates the script after 5 sec as expected. I have also tried with result=p.stdout.readlines() and then it also run as expected.

i have also tried executing it with the windows utils like psexec or start, same same.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to implement something like *nohup* that you would find on any \*nix system. Don't know if there's an equivalent on Windoze. In other words, you want to start some process and allow it to continue processing even if the instigator terminates

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: arrrrgh - you gave my a good hint. It is of course that the parent I'm testing with is terminating at once, and then the child is also stopped. ( just tested it ).
But then the question is, how do i get the child to continue, even if main script is stopped. i have tried start/psexec - didn't help